# Node.js - Socket.io-client does not emit data

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to build a simple `socket.io-client` using `nodejs`, but I'm facing a trouble...

I'm connecting with the `socket.io` (server), but I can't emit any data. Follow bellow my simple code:

**Client Side:**

```
var socketIO = require('socket.io-client')('http://serverdns:3000');

socketIO.on("dashboard", (data) => {
    console.log(data);
});

socketIO.on('connect', function(){ 

    console.log("Connected with the translator service.");
    socketIO.emit('dashboard', 'teste');


});

socketIO.on('disconnect', function(){ 

    console.log("Disconnected from the translator service");

});

socketIO.on('error', function(err){ 

    console.log(err);

});
```

`Socket.io` version: 2.1.1 (I've tried to use old versions but the same problem happens).

The `connect` event works, the log "Connected with the translator service." is generated, but `emit` does not work.

**Server side:**

```
var server = require('http').createServer();
var ioServer = require('socket.io')(server, { pingInterval: 2000, pingTimeout: 60000, cookie: false });

class SocketServer {

    constructor() {

        var self = this;

        ioServer.on('connection', function (client) {

            console.log('[SOCKETIO] AVAILABLE');

            client.on('main', self.main);
            client.on('disconnect', self.disconnect);

        });

        server.listen(3000);

    }

    getSocket(){
        return ioServer;
    }

    main(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }

    disconnect() {

        console.log("[SOCKETIO] DISCONNECTED");
    }

}

module.exports = new SocketServer();
```

Anyone can help me? 
Are there anything I'm not seeing?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you are emitting to the event `dashboard` from client. But on the server side you have no code that is handling that event. You are currently logging the event `main` which does not match with what you're emitting. Try `client.on('dashboard', self.dashboard)`. Make your own `dashboard` function.

Comment: But in client side I handle the event `'dashboard'`. Do I need to handle in both?

Comment: Yes. `socketIO.emit('dashboard', 'test')` is basically saying you are sending to `dashboard` so you will have to handle `dashboard` on server.